# vb.net if statement on webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net

Morning! (atleast in the US its morning).

I have an app with multiple buttons that load different sites using the webbrowser control.  I have the below code to auto login to an email website.  However, if I browse to another site and then click the email signin button to execute the below code, it errors out.  It errors out because it already signed me in to the site the first time and now since the credentials are cached it logs me right in and bypasses the login page.

How do I check if the login page doesn't exist, then exit sub.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(My.Settings.emailURL)
            WaitForPageLoad()
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user").InnerText = My.Settings.emailUN
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwd").InnerText = My.Settings.emailPW
            'WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("remember_me").SetAttribute("checked", "false")
            WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.forms(0).submit()
```

I tried the below but it didn't work:

```
If WebBrowser1.Navigate(My.Settings.emailURL) <> My.Settings.emailURL
```

Im assuming it didn't work because its a navigate command

Comment: You made it work for one site, its DOM has elements named "user" and "passwd".  The odds that another site will have those exact same elements are of course exceedingly low.  You will have to customize this code for each individual site.  Including any checks if a login is actually required.

Comment: Its the same site, basically what is happening is this.  I have a form that has 3 buttons on it, each button goes to a different website.  One of the websites is a webmail.  If the user clicks on say another button and goes to cnn.com on the webbrowser control, and then clicks on webmail again, it fails because it tries to enter is a UN and PW, but since he already signed in and its the same session, it autologs him right in

Comment: Then check the DOM first to look for anything that says "login".  If it is not there, or says "logout", then you don't want to do this.

Comment: The Comcast site is tricky, theres no ID, its just href link to log you out.  How could I do something like:

If webbrowser1.URL StartsWith

If I can check the URL of the webbrowser I can write an if statement

Comment: Or can I parse the page and say if sign out text exists anywhere on page?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The web address is unique if you're signed in and displays a static web url, so I did a small if statement.

```
If WebBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(My.Settings.webmailURL)
Exit Sub
Else
Sign in......
end if
```

Hans thanks for the help, you got me thinking.